# getting info about threads in gdb/ddd

Tags: multithreading, debugging, gdb, ddd-debugger

I am debugging a multi threaded application using `ddd`.

At the same time each second I can see on DDD **console out** that a new thread is created

```
 [NewThread 0x455fc940 (LWP 27373)]
```

and destroyed immediately after it.

```
 [Thread 0x455fc940  (LWP 27373) exited]
```

After few minutes I have this text out

```
 [NewThread 0x455fc940 (LWP 27363)]
 [Thread 0x455fc940  (LWP 27363) exited]
 [NewThread 0x455fc940 (LWP 27367)]
 [Thread 0x455fc940  (LWP 27367) exited]
 [NewThread 0x455fc940 (LWP 27373)]
 [Thread 0x455fc940  (LWP 27373) exited]
 ...and so on..
```

with this LWP increasing.

The threas comes and go too fast to be displayed using the window  I got clicking on Status->Thread. Can you address me a bit about how to get information about that thread?

Do you know why this LWP is increasing all the time?
More important how to get the function that is lunched into that thread?

Thank you all
AFG

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`LWP` is an acronym and stands for Light Weight Process. It is in effect the *thread ID* of each newly spawned thread.

On what to do about those spawning and dying threads: you could try set a break point at `clone`, which is he system call (? am I correct?) which starts a new thread at a given function.

Note: When breaking at `clone` you know from where the thread will be started, but don't actually have a thread, you can then however set break points at the functions given as argument to `clone`...

That is, start your program from gdb or ddd with the `start` command, which sets a temporary break point at the program entry point (i.e. `main`), than set a break point at `clone`, continue and see what happens ;).

**Update**: setting a break point at `clone` works for me... at least in my test. I should add that this is linux specific - and is actually what `pthread_create` uses.

Answer (score 4):

Set a breakpoint at pthread_create.

```
(gdb) break pthread_create
Breakpoint 1 at 0x20c49ba5cabf44
```

Now when you run it, it will stop execution when the next call to create a thread happens, and you can type `where` to see who the caller was.